# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::StrictgitSanitizer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to run rake for testing my Rails 3.2.3 app and I'm getting this weird error

```
gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:206:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::StrictgitSanitizer (NameError)
```

My specs files are completely empty, I havn't started writing test code yet, just blank auto generated spec files.

I need ideas on how to debug this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you accidentally pasted the word `git` into `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict` inside your **config/environment.rb**. Somehow, ActiveModel is using `Strictgit` as part of a name, where it should be using something like `Logger` or `Strict`.

I just looked at line 206 of **gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb**, where the error occurs. The method surrounding line 206 is:

```
def mass_assignment_sanitizer=(value)
  self._mass_assignment_sanitizer = if value.is_a?(Symbol)
    const_get(:"#{value.to_s.camelize}Sanitizer").new(self)
  else
    value
  end
end
```

As far as I see, `mass_assignment_sanitizer=(value)` only gets called with the values of `:logger` and `:strict` in Rails itself.

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot. I was wondering what could strictgit possibly be.